# Flex module no more a module when extended?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have created a module in Flex like below:

**modules/ModuleBase.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
 // components here
</mx:Module>
```

So far so good - when this file is saved **ModuleBase.swf** is generated.

Now I extend the above and create another class:

**ModuleChild.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ModuleBase xmlns="modules.*" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    // more components here
</ModuleBase>
```

Now, What I had expected was for Flex Builder to generate **ModuleChild.swf**. Which doesn't really happen. Bummer.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing for sometime figured out the solution:

1. Right click your project and select **properties**
2. Click **Flex Modules** in the left menu
3. Find your module, select it and **Edit**
4. In **Optimize SWF size** select **Do not Optimize**
5. Be happy :)